# Layout subviews in TableViewCell without adding to NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a subclass of a NSTableViewCell that has several controls in it, and I need the width of one of them to calculate the height for the row.

Since its not allowed to get the cell from tableView:heightOfRow, I need to calculate the height taking into account the width of a textField thats inside the cell and the string that goes in that row.

I figured I'd create a single static cell, give it a frame with the current width and make it calculate and perform its layout and get the resulting width for a textField width.

Here is the code thats supposed to get me the width of the "nameTextField"

```
    +(float)nameTextFieldWidthForTaskTableType:(TaskTableType )type compactSize:(BOOL)compactSize totalCellWidth:(float)totalWidth{
    static TaskCellView *taskCell = nil;
    if (taskCell == nil) {
        taskCell = [[TaskCellView alloc]initWithCompactSize:compactSize taskTableType:type identifier:@"notUsed"];
    }

    if (taskCell.frame.size.width != totalWidth) {
        taskCell.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, totalWidth, 25);
        [taskCell updateConstraints];

    }

    NSTextField *nameTextField = [taskCell viewForComponent:kTaskCellComponentName];
    return nameTextField.frame.size.width;

}
```

The cell subviews are constraint based. And they work ok. But here, the nameTextField frame always is zero. Does the cell need a superview to do its layout ? Or what else could be missing ?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
   [taskCell layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
```